# If condition into a grid - ExtJS

Tags: image, if-statement, extjs, frameworks

In my project I want to add a different picture in a column according to a specific value defined in another column.
I'm ok with adding the picture, but not with the If condition.
My code :

```
initComponent: function() {

    this.columns = [
   {header: 'ID du CPE', dataIndex: 'ID',  flex: 1},
       {header: 'Modèle', dataIndex: 'Modele', flex: 1},
   {header: 'Firmware', dataIndex: 'firmware', flex: 1},
   {header: 'Année MeS', dataIndex: 'annee', flex: 1},
       {header: 'Statut', dataIndex: 'statut', flex: 1},
   {header: 'Alerte', dataIndex: 'alerte', flex: 1, 

    renderer: function(value, metadata, record) {
        if (record.get('OK')) { 
        return '<img src="ressource/image/edit.png"/>';
    }}
   } 
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

The columns of the grid are populated by a JSON file. The column "statut" is populated with random string, like "OK", or "NOK".
What I want is to add a specific picture into the column "Alerte" when the value in the column "statut" is "OK", and another one when the value is "NOK".

I don't really get the record.get usage.
I still don't know if I can do this only from adding code in my view file.

Comment: `record.get('Statut')` will get the value of the `Statut` field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third param of the renderer is the record that is rendered into that row. So you can do this like

```
renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
        var val = record.get('statut');
        if (val  == 'OK') { 
            return '<img src="ressource/image/edit.png"/>';
        }else if (val == 'NOK') { 
            return '<img src="ressource/image/edit.png"/>';
        }
        return ''; // default -> no image at all
    }
}
```

See the full [renderer api reference](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) for additional information how to use it

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But now my column "Alerte" is blank (I can't see the lines anymore) :(

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Just a point, I had to put the dataIndex in the container of record.get() (=statut) and not the name of the header (=Statut).

Comment: @SecularBoy You're welcome ;) Yeah, I meant that but didn't saw the upper case. I fixed it. As you are new to Stackoverflow; You may also consider to upvote any answer that helped you by finding a solution. The best one may also be choosen as 'answer' as you had done.

Comment: I already tried to upvote but a pop-up says "Vote up requires 15 reputation" :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also use viewConfig which is a config object that will be applied to the grid's UI view as :

```
viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
                        if(record.get('statut')=='OK')
                        return  "OKimage.class"; //css class
                        else
                            return "NOKimage.class";
          }
  }
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to add a rowclass when one column needs to a display a image.

Comment: Yeah my bad (: If their is a need to apply certain CSS class to any rows based on data then that would work.